# Can't restart nginx server : failed to start a high performance web server and reverse

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I can't restart nginx server. the following error encountered. I suspect the cause could be that there's another service running on port 80.

I tried listing down all services running on port 80. But it does not show any.

```
root@ubuntu:/# sudo service nginx restart
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@ubuntu:/# systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-04-21 15:21:14 EDT; 53s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 121217 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run
  Process: 120160 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, stat
  Process: 121540 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exi
 Main PID: 120162 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 21 15:21:13 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy s
Apr 21 15:21:14 ubuntu nginx[121540]: nginx: [emerg] "listen" directive is not allowed here in 
Apr 21 15:21:14 ubuntu nginx[121540]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test fail
Apr 21 15:21:14 ubuntu systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 21 15:21:14 ubuntu systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 21 15:21:14 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse
```

Comment: `I suspect the cause could be that there's another service running on port 80.` No, the cause is that you have an error in your config file: `nginx: [emerg] "listen" directive is not allowed here in configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.